# How to connect an Android with a single USB-C to both Ethernet adapter & USB at the same time

Tags: usb, android, cable, cabling

**Scenario**

I have a running setup like this

[image]

My laptop is connected to a USB hub on which attached 2 smartphones.

The phones are plugged in NOT FOR CHARGING, but for debugging apps on the phones.

Now, I need the phones to also be connected to ethernet (wifi won't work for my specific case) at the same time they're being connected to the hub.

How do I do that?

**Research**

I saw there are `USB-C to Ethernet & USB-A` adapters like these:

[here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/surface-usb-c-to-ethernet-and-usb-adapter/8WT81CGLRBLP/1JJG?source=googleshopping&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIm_-thIi06QIVF4-GCh1wgwdcEAQYByABEgIJKfD_BwE%3aG%3as&s_kwcid=AL!4249!3!357170572065!!!g!877554252637!&OCID=AID2000007_SEM_EAIaIQobChMIm_-thIi06QIVF4-GCh1wgwdcEAQYByABEgIJKfD_BwE%3aG%3as&activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab), [here](https://www.cablestogo.com/product/29747/usb-c-to-ethernet-adapter-with-3-port-usb-hub-black?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=Shopping&utm_campaign=SEM&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIicSkmIq06QIVJoNaBR2L3QmBEAQYASABEgI4f_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). They're all in the form of:

Male USB-C <======> female Ethernet & female USB-A

A set up using this type of adapter would look like this:

[image]

I'm not sure why but I have run into situations where simply connecting smartphones to multiple hubs before it reaches a laptop will prevent the laptop from programmatically access the device. The devices are only charged.

I'm not sure if the setup above will work. Will I be able to programmatically access the devices?

Comment: Please explain why Wifi is not an option to you. Are your devices rooted? If yes you can try to perform reverse tethering using the existing USB connection. Hence no additional hardware would be needed. If you only need HTTP(S) access on the phone this is even possible without root using a HTTP proxy on the PC and performing port-forwarding from the device to the proxy.

Comment: I can't use wifi because it's not stable enough for my use case. Our devices can't be rooted. The proxy solution is what I have right now, though it's slightly different from your suggestion.

Comment: If you want you can make WiFi rock stable. Just place the devices and a WiFi router/access point (with reduced sending power) in a Faraday cage.

Answer (score 1):

The USB hubs connected to the phones are assuming that the phone will be the "host" device, which is correct because that means the Ethernet will work. The USB A ports on those hubs will also assume the same.

USB is **not** a peer to peer network. you cannot have multiple USB host devices connected together. As such a laptop (USB host) cannot work together with the other USB hubs because they already have a host each.

You will have to either get rid of the USB Ethernet adaptors, or connect to the phones via Ethernet for debugging.